# CLion "This file does not belong to any project target" when added to cmake

Tags: cmake, clion

I wanted to look at a codebase of [OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend) in CLion, but code insight feature don't work. I thought only adding the file in cmake is required for CLion to provide the insights.

[image: file is registered in cmake here]

[image]
the header files root directory is also included

```
include_directories(BEFORE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
```

Comment: I would try `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` or `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. The latter changes in a subdirectory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245738/in-clion-header-only-library-file-does-not-belong-to-any-project-target-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed when I resolved dependencies so that cmake run without errors. (but don't know how exactly clion uses the CMakeLists.txt file, if I knew, it could be evident)