# Cannot "Mark Directory as" anything but a python namespace package in CLion 2020.3

Tags: c++, clion

I am working with CLion and when loading a project from a valid CMakeLists file I get the warning that none of the files belong to any project target. This is annoying and I found a solution here that seems to work for most people.

[In CLion, header only library: file "does not belong to any project target, code insight features might not work properly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245738/in-clion-header-only-library-file-does-not-belong-to-any-project-target-code)

However when I try and mark an include directory as part of the project there is not an option. The only options is to mark it has a python namespace package. Googling for this issue didn't seem to turn anything up. Does anyone know why that option would not be there?

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the CLion configuration in the containing folder then reopen the project.

`rm -rf .idea`

It did work for me.